# Delete Parent Directory With sub directory if no file inside

Tags: java, file

I have one parent folder in which multiple sub - directory and so on. I have to delete all those directory and sub-directory in which no file inside.

eg :

```
A - parent (no file inside)
|
B-sub-dir (no file inside)
|
c- sub-dir of B (no file inside)
|
D- no file inside
```

***in this case i have to delete Parent folder A***

I have tried like this

```
    static List<File> fileListToDelete = new ArrayList<File>();
static List<File> getListOfBlankDirectoryToDelete(File parentFolder) {


    for (File fileentry : parentFolder.listFiles()) {

            if (fileentry.isDirectory()&& fileentry.listFiles().length == 0) {
                fileentry.delete();
            } else if (fileentry.isDirectory()) {
                getListOfBlankDirectoryToDelete(fileentry);
            }

    }

    return fileListToDelete;
}

static void deleteBlankDirectory(File parentFolder){
    List<File> fileListForDeletion = getListOfBlankDirectoryToDelete(parentFolder);
    for(File file : fileListForDeletion){
        file.delete();
    }
}
```

In above code, i tried to find the directories having no file inside and delete but it doesn't delete all blank directory.

Comment: What is your question/what have you tried?

Comment: @bajrangi can specify things you have tried if yes what was the issue.. the code you used..

Comment: @1337joe my question is simple that how to delete a folder along with sub folder if there is no files inside in entire hierarchy.

Comment: provide your method `getListOfBlankDirectoryToDelete(fileentry);`...what it does?? is that working fine...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

first you have to delete all subfolders and then delete main folder.

when you delete main folder and if it contains any folder may be blank, then main folder is unable to delete.

i have some sample code to delete all the subfolders and main folder.

```
    File folder = new File("folder_path_to_delete");
    ArrayList<File> foldersToDelete = listFolders(folder);
    foldersToDelete.add(folder);
    for(File folderToDelete : foldersToDelete) {
        folderToDelete.delete();
    }
    System.out.println(foldersToDelete + "  deleted");
```

and method `listFolders(folder)` is like this

```
public static ArrayList<File> listFolders(File folder) {
    ArrayList<File> subFolders = new ArrayList<>();
    File[] folders = folder.listFiles(new FileFilter() {

        @Override
        public boolean accept(File pathname) {
            return pathname.isDirectory();
        }
    });
    for(File subFolder : folders) {
        subFolders.addAll(listFolders(subFolder));
    }
    subFolders.addAll(Arrays.asList(folders));
    return subFolders;
}
```

it will work..

Note: it will not work when there is any file in any subfolder. It will delete only blank folders..

Answer (score 0):

You can try this...

```
 private void deleteFileDIR(File file){
    if(file.isDirectory()){
        if(file.list().length==0){
            try{
            file.delete();
            }catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }else{
           String files[] = file.list();

           for (String temp : files) {
              File fileDelete = new File(file, temp);
              deleteFileDIR(fileDelete);
           }
           if(file.list().length==0){
             try{
             file.delete();
             }catch (Exception e) {
            }

           }
        }
    }
```